# Probability of colisson for classes of hash functions

Tags: probability-theory, hashing

I am going through some old exams in one of my courses, and I don't have access to solutions. I've found a problem which I am not sure how to tackle. I am not looking for the answer but some help/guidance if possible.

Consider a class of hash functions , $\mathcal{H}$, over a finite universe ${U}$ into $\{0, ... , n-1\}$. Where $|U| > 1$ and $n > 1$.

Show that for any family of hash functions $\mathcal{H}$ the following holds:
$$
Pr[h(u_1) = h(u_2)] \geq \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{|U|}
$$
Here, the probability is over the choice of the hash function $h$ drawn uniformly at random from the family $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Is the required "$\forall u_1, u_2$" after the $Pr_{h \in \mathcal{H}}[$ or before it?

Comment: No, it is not required for all $u_1$ and $u_2$, but for two choosen "worst ones".

Comment: Let me restate: for the formula to be valid, $u_1$ and $u_2$ **must be bound**. Is that binder "$\exists$" or is it "$\forall$"? Where does it appear in the formula?

Comment: Can you edit the question to specify what $u_1$ and $u_2$ are (or how they are chosen).